# How to export a xlsx to pdf/A on the cli

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf

I've tried both with `lowriter` and `localc` yet it always looks very bad and isn't PDF/A.

Ive tried:

- `localc / lowriter --convert-to pdf *.xlsx`

Comment: Please explain what you exactly tried with `localc`. This command does not create PDF by default.

Comment: @vanadium I added the command to the question

Comment: " yet it always looks very bad"  if you do not provide info on how you want it converted it will guess. Use `unoconv`  https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/doc2odt.1.html It has dozens of options to format the conversion.

Comment: Can you open LibreOffice Calc and set PDF options to "Archive PDF/A" in the GUI and try the CLI commands again? (File > Export as PDF > General). I always use PDF/A and when I execute `localc --convert-to pdf *.xlsx` it output PDF/A. I can only guess it picks up your GUI preferences because there is no CLI argument available.

Comment: @TomBrossman Thank you that fixed it. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CLI option to require PDF/A output, however if you first set it in the GUI preferences then the CLI export will use PDF/A.

Open Calc or Writer, go to File > Export as PDF > General (tab) and select which PDF/A type you prefer. Then the next time you use the CLI it will work as expected.